# Should this be referred to Legal SE?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

[This post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153085/game-publishers-and-republishers) is a first question asking about international copyright law between two specific countries, and just so happens to be about attempting to liscense a videogame.

I'm not really sure this is on-topic for Game Development, but @Philipp has already edited it, so I'm second guessing myself.

There are also a lot of discussions, such as [this one](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283/proper-solution-for-legal-questions) or [this one](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/are-legal-questions-on-or-off-topic-revisited), in Meta which address what is or isn't a relevant legal question for Game Development. After reading through some of them, I still think the question seems Off-Topic.

Anyone else think this should be flagged as Off-Topic? I don't want to flag it and end up discouraging a new member unnecessarily.

Comment: woah, didnt realize the "...Revisited" legal post was so new its eyes are still blinking in the morning light. The question in question (see what i did there) popped up in my "First Post" review queue, and Im not sure what to do with it.

Comment: It may not be on-topic here, but it doesn't fit the criteria for migration, so it's going to stay here unless the OP themselves re-ask on Law.

Comment: Should I flag it then?

Comment: That's up to you; I don't want to tell you how to think. From my perspective it isn't _so bad_ as to warrant my unilateral intervention. It's up the community.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I'll leave it be. I've only recently started trying to flag posts but it's so few and far between my radar still needs calibration

Answer (score 1):

I felt it was on topic enough to warrant attempting an answer. That being said, I don't think it's a particularly good question. It doesn't demonstrate much research & as written, it's applicability to others is limited.

In general, I tend to flag 'em as I see 'em. If the mods disagree, your flag will be declined. If you don't understand the reason for being declined, you can always ask (and if more than a couple in a row have been declined, you probably should).