# Is Q about negociating republishing other games on-topic? (alternative take & clarification of rule)

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

(This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153085/game-publishers-and-republishers) is already being discussed for another [reason](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/should-this-be-referred-to-legal-se) on whether or not it is on-topic or off-topic.)

The help centre includes "publishing" under project management.

> project management (testing, team management, scheduling, publishing, etc)

My interpretation is that this applies to one's own game project as part of protect management. And has to be an integral part of one the last steps of game development (getting it published).

Edit: moved my opinion to an answer to have a place to vote separate from the meta question.

Answer (score 4):

> This (to me) is a question about how to conduct a generic business negotiation, not specific to game development, and not about developing a game nor being a game developer unless it's about self-publishing or negotiating your own game's publication.

I think the topic is relevant to game development; we're talking about negotiating a deal for IP rights to a game, and the usage of those rights in a game publishing context which is something game development professionals familiar with the process could give unique insight on. I've thought about answering it myself, however...

...I'm not sure it's on topic because it's so *broad*. It's basically one step away from the game publishing equivalent for "how do I get started?" and thus I've been on the fence about it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the points about it being on-topic as relevant to game development.
I don't think it's necessarily too broad. The concept is broad & part of the question is asking about the the concept in very general terms. However, OP also has provided a context - they tried something & it didn't work they way they expected & they're trying to figure out why that might be the case.

Taken as a debugging question (albeit oof process rather than code), I think it passes.

To be fair, it could be better: OP could have more clearly indicated the relative size & reputation of their business as well as that of the IP being sought.

Answer (score 0):

Republishing other games (not porting, not updating, not adding DLC) seem no different than negotiating & acquiring rights to republish a movie, book, music album.

This is a question about how to conduct a generic business negotiation, not specific to game development, and not about developing a game nor being a game developer unless it's about self-publishing or negotiating your own game's publication.

Comment: Those upvoting this should consider voting to close the question too :P

Answer (score 0):

There is no better site (no business SE, no publishing/licensing SE) so in any case it should stay on GameDev.SE (for now) as it is the site most related to this topic.

Comment: I can't vote on my own answers but this would be my vote. I think there should be a business.SE and Qs on running a publishing business should go there. But they can stay here for now.

Comment: When I asked about migrating a question to SO, I was told that the absence or presence of another SE shouldn't be a factor.  If the community consensus is that it was not on-topic here (due to subject matter or any other criteria), then we should close it. We shouldn't keep barely on-topic things that don't have a better place to go & we shouldn't throw out on-topic things that might also fit other SEs.